# Interpretation of logistic PCA loadings and why loadings depend on number components extracted

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, binary-data

I am using Andrew J. Landgraf package `logisticPCA` to perform PCA on 41 binary variables. The purpose is the find main combinations of diseases in the sample and use it to model cost later.

There are two questions which I would like to seek clarification:
1) How do I interpret the loadings? Is it the same as regular PCA? I am taking an arbitrary cutoff of |0.15| as a criteria to select 'important' diseases in a component.
2) I am planning to consider the first components as start for further analysis but I realized of the size of the loadings depend on the number of components extracted. This would be problem if I say decide to look at the second component later and realized that the 'important' diseases has changed.

Here is a sample of my output:

```
print(logpca1)
> 430000 rows and 41 columns
  Rank 1 solution with m=5
  13.00% of deviance explained
  40 iterations to converge

> load1=as.data.frame(logpca1$U)
> row.names(load1)=names(df)
> load1
          V1
D1      -0.48
D2      -0.27
D3      -0.12
D4      -0.10
D5      -0.11
D6      -0.12
D7      -0.69
D8      -0.17
...

print(logpca2)
> 430000 rows and 41 columns
  Rank 2 solution with m=5
  23.01% of deviance explained
  47 iterations to converge
> load2=as.data.frame(logpca2$U)
> row.names(load2)=names(df)
> load2
          V1      V2
D1      -0.47   -0.23
D2      -0.31   -0.10
D3      -0.23    0.17
D4      -0.17    0.08
D5      -0.31    0.47
D6      -0.36    0.44
D7      -0.30   -0.61
D8      -0.23   -0.02
...
```

Comment: The algorirhm is iterative fitting one, that's why the number of components/factors to extract must be known in advance. And that's why loadings depend on this number specified. That is like in factor analysis.